# Making Django queries with localized dates

Tags: python, django, date, django-models, internationalization

In my form I have a DateField called booking_date that is rendered with the AdminDateWidget. The contents of the booking_date field needs to be internationalized. The problem appears when I want to use the value of the field in something like this:

```
booking = Booking.objects.get(booking_number='BN34D', booking_date='2010-11-21')
```

But if my date format is **'%d.%m.%Y'**:

```
booking = Booking.objects.get(booking_number='BN34D', booking_date='21.11.2010')
```

I get a 'ValidationError: Enter a valid date in YYYY-MM-DD format'

How can I make the query regardless of the date format used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem using this:

```
from django.utils import formats

formats.get_format('DATE_INPUT_FORMATS')[0]
```

This format is then used for parsing the date like [xyld showed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5072190/making-django-queries-with-localized-dates/5072254#5072254).

Answer (score 4):

You should parse it first with a localized version of the strftime format.

```
from datetime import datetime
d = datetime.strptime('...')
booking.objects.get(..., booking_date=d.date())
```

Use these formats in `strptime`:

http://linux.die.net/man/3/strftime

You shouldn't rely on passing directly from the user into the query.

Looks like you should be doing the following from your specific example:

```
d = datetime.strptime('%d.%m.%Y')
booking = Booking.objects.get(booking_nmber='BN34D', booking_date=d)
```

Comment: Sorry, I keep using wikimedia markup for codeblocks instead of markdown... fixed so its viewable

Comment: How can I know the date format? Is there a way to access this format?

Comment: It would have been good to obtain this format using the current locale.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand your question, you don't know for sure in advance, which locale will be used. That can bring you into unsolvable problems. ("10-11-12" could be Oct 11, 2012 or Nov 12, 2010 or ...)

So you must have a limited, distinguishable set of possible formats. Then you can do:

```
POSSIBLE_FORMATS = ('%d.%m.%Y', '%Y-%m-%d', '...')

for f in POSSIBLE_FORMATS:
    try:
        d = datetime.date.strptime(date_str, f)
        break
    except ValueError:
        continue
    raise ValueError

booking = Booking.objects.get(booking_number='BN34D', booking_date=d)
```

Comment: In the formats.py file for german  DATE_INPUT_FORMATS[0] will return '%d.%m.%Y' and for english DATE_INPUT_FORMATS[0] will return '%Y-%m-%d'. I always know that I want the first element, so there is no ambiguity.

Comment: I am trying to solve this using FORMAT_MODULE_PATH: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5165634/advice-on-using-format-module-path