# Advice on using FORMAT_MODULE_PATH

Tags: python, django, date, internationalization, settings

From what I have read [`FORMAT_MODULE_PATH`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#format-module-path) allows to use custom formats.

How can I access the first value from [`DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#datetime-input-formats) in my application?

The `DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS` variable for german should be `'%d.%m.%Y'`, whereas for english should be `'%Y-%m-%d'`. I want to use the values from the formats.py files depending on the language.

I followed the [Django documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#format-module-path) for how to use the `FORMAT_MODULE_PATH` variable, but I don't get the expected results.

```
settings.py:
    USE_L10N = True
    USE_I18N = True
    FORMAT_MODULE_PATH = 'myproject.formats'


myproject/
    formats/
        __init__.py
        en/
            __init__.py
            formats.py
        de/
            __init__.py
            formats.py
```

I change the browser's language from English to German, and back and nothing happens with the date format. It is always `'%Y-%m-%d'`. The displayed date format is the value of `settings.DATE_INPUT_FORMATS[0]`.

Django version is 1.2.5 and Python version is 2.5.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't make it work using the FORMAT_MODULE_PATH setting, but I have managed to this using formats.get_format('DATE_INPUT_FORMATS')[0]. You can find this in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5072190/making-django-queries-with-localized-dates/5195248#5195248).

Answer (score 2):

In Django 1.3, I have this working properly:

in `settings.py`:

```
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Amsterdam'
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'nl_NL'
FORMAT_MODULE_PATH = 'settings.locale'
```

In `settings/locale/nl/formats.py`:

```
DATETIME_FORMAT = 'j F Y \o\m H:i'
```